# Top aligning chemmacros pictures

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, alignment, chemmacros

How can I top align these two `chemmacros` pictures? I tried with `tabular`, but maybe I forgot something

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=mhchem,modules=newman} % Loads mhchem package and newman module


    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
        \newman(120){\ce{H},H,H,\ce{H},H,H} &
        \newman(80){\ce{H},H,H,\ce{H},H,H}
        \end{tabular}
     \end{figure}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Lower both formulas by their height.

I changed the loading part, bacause a warning appears if `module` is given in `\chemsetup`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{upgreek}% to avoid an annoying warning
\usepackage[module=newman]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\raisebox{-\height}{\newman(120){H,H,H,H,H,H}}\qquad
\raisebox{-\height}{\newman(80){H,H,H,H,H,H}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]